# xamaring Android Webview always trying to load local file

Tags: xamarin, webview

So this is strange, but if I load a local html file into a WebView using LoadUrl it tries to load all resources using file://

So for example this page loads google web fonts as an external resource.

This only happens on Android iOS works fine.

Has anybody had the same issue?

**Note:** I'm using the HybridWebViewRenderer if that makes a difference, I also do not have control over the source html files.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? In addition to this, are you trying to load the file using a public url?

Comment: I suggest you post a demo so that others can test it for you.